# Can not make qmqtt

Tags: qt

I had previously installed qt4. Now, I have installed QT5.7. I am trying to compile the qmqtt project to generate  the libqmqtt file. Qmake is fine. But make gives the following error.

Link:
https://github.com/emqtt/qmqtt

```
g++ -c -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++0x -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_MTDEV -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_BUILD_MQTT_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt -I/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt -I/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/include -I/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/include/qmqtt -I../../include -I../../include/qmqtt -I/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/include/qmqtt/1.0.0 -I/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/include/qmqtt/1.0.0/qmqtt -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I.moc -I. -o .obj/qmqtt_routedmessage.o /home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt/qmqtt_routedmessage.cpp
g++ -c -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++0x -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_MTDEV -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_BUILD_MQTT_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt -I/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt -I/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/include -I/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/include/qmqtt -I../../include -I../../include/qmqtt -I/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/include/qmqtt/1.0.0 -I/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/include/qmqtt/1.0.0/qmqtt -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I.moc -I. -o .obj/qmqtt_router.o /home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt/qmqtt_router.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:47:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QObject:1,
                 from /home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt/qmqtt_router.h:38,
                 from /home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt/qmqtt_router.cpp:33:
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs_impl.h: In instantiation of ‘struct QtPrivate::AreArgumentsCompatible<QMQTT::Message, QMQTT::Message>’:
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs_impl.h:599:21:   required from ‘struct QtPrivate::CheckCompatibleArguments<QtPrivate::List<const QMQTT::Message&>, QtPrivate::List<const QMQTT::Message&> >’
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:241:80:   required from ‘static QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::Object*, Func2, Qt::ConnectionType) [with Func1 = void (QMQTT::Client::*)(const QMQTT::Message&); Func2 = void (QMQTT::RouteSubscription::*)(const QMQTT::Message&); typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object = QMQTT::Client; typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::Object = QMQTT::RouteSubscription]’
/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt/qmqtt_router.cpp:52:87:   required from here
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs_impl.h:573:42: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class QMQTT::Message’
         enum { value = sizeof(test(dummy())) == sizeof(int) };
                                          ^
In file included from /home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt/qmqtt_router.cpp:35:0:
/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt/qmqtt_client.h:95:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class QMQTT::Message’
 class Message;
       ^
In file included from /home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt/qmqtt_global.h:35:0,
                 from /home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt/qmqtt_router.h:36,
                 from /home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt/qmqtt_router.cpp:33:
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h: In instantiation of ‘static QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::Object*, Func2, Qt::ConnectionType) [with Func1 = void (QMQTT::Client::*)(const QMQTT::Message&); Func2 = void (QMQTT::RouteSubscription::*)(const QMQTT::Message&); typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object = QMQTT::Client; typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::Object = QMQTT::RouteSubscription]’:
/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/src/mqtt/qmqtt_router.cpp:52:87:   required from here
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:669:47: error: static assertion failed: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible.
 #define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
                                               ^
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:228:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X’
         Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X((QtPrivate::CheckCompatibleArguments<typename SignalType::Arguments, typename SlotType::Arguments>::value),
         ^
make[2]: *** [.obj/qmqtt_router.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/build/src/mqtt'
make[1]: *** [sub-mqtt-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sm/qt_applications/qmqtt/qmqtt-master/build/src'
make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

Comment: very old question.. but you should try compiling as an administrator. for linux do sudo make and sudo make install. and for windows open the cmd as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Spent a lot of time. After compiling by Qt 5.7.0, there was no Dll-files in the folder "release". I looking at the compilation log and I saw that there was created the folder "lib" in the root of the disk with the project, there I found Dll. But work with DLL allows you to work on Windows. I need on Android.

In [github](https://github.com/emqx/qmqtt/issues/17#issuecomment-72792264) someone suggests just use it as plain code.

I rewrite it to "plain code" and made example-project. [It is here](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/gEE8/XpaQUbZtL). There is two folders: project and mosquitto for using mqtt on localhost